# Strange lines in specgram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.specgram` to create spectrograms of recordings of spoken words. For a reason unknown to me the spectrograms have strange lines in them as seen from the images below.

I am wondering what is causing these lines and how can I get rid of them?

[image: Example spectrogram]
[image: Example spectrogram]

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without the code+data used to generate this, but it looks to me like the 'lines' are actually some kind of underlying discrete and dramatic change in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @farenorth is right.

When the spectrogram is calculated then for each timestep (x-axis) a certain grayscale  is picked for a given intensity. Let's assume the grayscale is set globally.  If suddenly you have higher intensities in a new timestep, the grayscale would saturate.

This would be a real problem if you were to work in real-time, since you could be starting with very quiet audio that suddenly becomes loud, but you'll have to pick a grayscale vs intensity ratio at the beginning based on knowledge of past audiotracks.

So the approach of 'mlab.specgram' is to to scale all timesteps independently. Therefore if there is sudden change during a timestep, things don't look comparable to the neighboring steps, which is what @farenorth pointed out.

A synthetic example below. The top plot is just a chirped sinewave, the bottom plots are the same with a sudden bang added.

```
'''specgram(x, NFFT=256, Fs=2,detrend=mlab.detrend_none,
        window=mlab.window_hanning, noverlap=128,
        cmap=None, xextent=None, pad_to=None, sides='default',
        scale_by_freq=None, mode='default')'''
  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
 
%matplotlib inline

time= np.arange(1,5,0.0004)
time=np.linspace(1,5,1024*16)
f= 50+ time*50 
#add a bang
bang=np.ones(len(time))
bang[ len(time)/2:len(time)*3/4]=100


chirp1= np.sin(2*np.pi*f*time) 
chirp2= np.sin(2*np.pi*f*time) *bang

p.figure(figsize=((20,8)))
p.subplot(221)
p.plot(chirp1)
p.subplot(222)
p.specgram(chirp1 ,noverlap=0,cmap=p.cm.gray)

p.subplot(223)
p.plot(chirp2)
p.subplot(224)
p.specgram(chirp2 ,noverlap=0,cmap=p.cm.gray)
p.show()
```

[image]

You can't get rid of that with *specgram*, since there is no option for global scaling.  But you could easily roll your own STFT or better, a Gabor spectrogram (STFT with Gaussian window if I understand it right).